# convert a string on github pages anywhere in documents

Tags: github, markdown, jekyll, github-pages, liquid

first question so please don't treat me too harshly (going mad here)

**I am trying to convert one string to another, for all .md files for a github-pages hosted repository.**

`[[this]]` -> `[this](this)`

It feels like something trivial, but to be honest I don't even know where to start.
I basically want to have apply a kind of "find and replace" function for every .md file for every instance of a [[x]] in it.

**I tried looking at every documentation**

But either I am unable to understand it, or seems that it is impossible on git-hub pages.
Liquid is no help afaik (because you need to explicitly provide an input? I can't define a general conversion for the whole page, right?)

Afaik I can't edit jekyll plugins on github pages without local hosting, and none of the whitelisted plugins seem to help.

**If it's indeed impossible:**
Then I will have to go locally host Jekyll. In that case, I would love any tips on how it *could* be possible. For example by creating custom plugins.

I really would love your help - thank you in advance!

Comment: Is this a one-off process, or are you pulling this data from another source and need it converted regularly?

Comment: The latter! What I had in mind was for [Obsidian](https://obsidian.md) to act as a stand-alone blogging environment. It uses local .md files, so I wanted to just sync the Obsidian folder with github, so I can utilize the smooth workflow and natural organisation in Obsidian (Backlinks auto-sync/update in Obsidian too). I only need the [[backlinks]] to convert to [this](format) for this to work afaik!

Ty for responding and thinking along with me ^^

Comment: I realized maybe it's easier to have an intermediate local folder, which copies the files in the obsidian folder to another, but also applying that updating of [[backlinks]] to [this](format), and then sync *that* folder with github. Reckon that's more feasible?

Comment: Obsidian seems to use CommonMark-flavoured markdown, so I'd advice using this plugin for GitHub Pages: https://github.com/github/jekyll-commonmark-ghpages

Comment: It looks like the double square bracket links are an Obsidian-specific addition to CommonMark, so you'd probably need to write either a pre-process script or plugin in Jekyll that rewrites it. GitHub Pages doesn't allow plugins though and there isn't a replace with regex filter by default.